# React-native createRef is not working properly

Tags: react-native

I have class component in which I'm trying to use refs.

Here is how I create it

```
    inputRef = React.createRef()
```

And here is how I use it

```
<Input
                                ref={(input)=>this.inputRef=input}
                                secureTextEntry={true}
                                style={styles.inputPassword}
                                onChangeText={(text) => {
                                    this.checkPassword(text);
                                    handleChange('password')(text);
                                }}
                            />
```

But no matter what I try it always console logs `null` any suggestions?

Comment: Where is your console.log ?

Comment: In another function

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
                         <Input
                            ref={this.inputRef}
                            secureTextEntry={true}
                            style={styles.inputPassword}
                            onChangeText={(text) => {
                                this.checkPassword(text);
                                handleChange('password')(text);
                            }}
                        />
```

Comment: But i m using class component not functional

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.inputField = React.createRef();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <input type="text" ref={this.inputField} />
      </View>
    );
  }  
}
```